# How do I get a WPF slider control with 3 thumbs

Tags: wpf, slider

I want to use a slider control which has 3 thumbs - they are not required to cross each other, but the user should be able to move any of the thumbs independently.

Background : I have created a [pairs trading application](http://www.quantcode.com/modules/mydownloads/singlefile.php?cid=15&lid=579) which needs input of :

1.training set begin date

2.training set end date or test set big date (they are same)

3.test set end date

I have done it using 3 slider controls placed one below the other, but it is confusing to use. I am hoping to use a single control instead if possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of any triple sliders out there, but Mindscape have a dual slider in their WPF Elements suite (http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/wpfelements/controls/wpf-dual-slider), and might be open to extending it to three thumbs.  (Disclosure: I work for Mindscape.)  It is a commercial component though - I don't know if that's an option for you.

Comment: Itowlson, Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, I can only afford a freebie because it is for an open source educational project

Comment: Sliders to set dates? Can't you use the Calendar control from http://wpf.codeplex.com ?

Comment: rolling the slider thumb makes it easier to see the cointegration property for diffecrent cross sections in time. (I am updating correlation stregth icon while the thumb position is changing)

Comment: Why/how are 3 separate slider controls more difficult to use than one monolithic control with 3 sliders built into it? You still have 3 thumbs...not sure what the difference could possibly be.

Comment: I want to move middle thumb to move the crossection of interest, otherwise for 3 sliders i have to move them manually each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to adapt the control on [here](http://wpfdaterangeslider.codeplex.com/) to have a third slider

Answer (score 0):

You can also find a good example, for creating slider with more than one thumb, [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx).